# Trouble with ggplot2 and POSIX x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R. While executing below line of code I've encountered an error (`Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number`) at the end of line ggplot2, details below. Not sure what causes this. Although I saw another post on a similar error however, it doesn't seem to be fully relevant to my code structure. Appreciate all inputs. Thanks.

```
setwd(("C:/Users/xx")
  library(ggplot2)
  library(forecast)
  library(dplyr)
  library(colortools)
  
  Master <- read.csv("master.csv") 
  class(Master$TIMESTAMP)
  
  Master$TIMESTAMP_posix <- as.POSIXct(Master$TIMESTAMP, format = "%D/%M/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  class(Master$TIMESTAMP_posix)
  
  (time_plot_2 <- ggplot(Master, aes(x = TIMESTAMP_posix, y = VWC_CS7)) +
      geom_line() +
      scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%Y", date_breaks = "1 day") +
      theme_classic())
```

Comment: Please share some sample data so we can reproduce the problem. The best way to share data is `dput(Master[1:10, ])` (for the first 10 rows). This will be a copy/pasteable R object including all class and structure information.

Comment: FYI, your `format=` looks suspect ... if you read [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html), the `%`-codes are case-sensitive. Specifically, days and months are lower-case `"%d"` and `"%m"`, respectively, so I think your format string is more likely `format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans and Gregor Thomas.
Upon careful look on my dataset I noted the date was in the order of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format. So I tweaked the format to below which worked.
'format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'